# How to set type when using setTemplate in action

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template

I am rewriting the template of `newsletter_manage_index` like this:

```
<newsletter_manage_index>
    <reference name="customer_newsletter">       
       <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/form/newsletter.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</newsletter_manage_index>
```

But I need to set the block type of that new template, 
e.g.

```
<template type="fekete_newsletter2go/form">fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/form/newsletter.phtml</template>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by deleting that block and after add that block with custom block type of that new template.

see below code

```
<newsletter_manage_index>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
         <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer_newsletter</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="fekete_newsletter2go/form" name="customer_newsletter" template="fekete/Newsletter2Go/customer/form/newsletter.phtml" />
    </reference>
</newsletter_manage_index>
```